Smartsheet Data Shuttle: Is there a way I can directly setup a data shuttle that brings records from a sheet to a data table as they get added in?
Newbie question, so I am thinking of setting up a workflow where I have an archive sheet in smartsheets that get populated after a certain period of time. As we all know, sheets can only hold around 20,000 rows while data tables can store up to 2 million records. Is there any way I can setup a data shuttle that automatically transfers records within the archive sheet onto the data table? I am unable to find answers in the smartsheet community.
I've tried setting up connections via sheets or creating a data table via data shuttle but always get stuck on the 'attachment name' portion of the source section, apparently, data shuttle does not recognize the records within a sheet but rather looks for an actual file attachment within the sheet.
